# Python PCA Implementation Low Success

Tags: python, pca, knn

I'm trying to implement PCA on python myself. I'm using KNN classifier on mnist dataset to check the sucess of my implementation but the success ratio is too low as %10 percentage. Can you please check my code and indicate what im doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

def PCA(data, ndimension): 
    x , y = data.shape
    mean_vec = np.mean(data, axis=0)
    mean_data = data - mean_vec
    cov_mat = mean_data.T.dot(mean_data) / (x-1)
    eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)
    eig_pairs = [(np.abs(eig_vals[i]), eig_vecs[:,i]) for i in range(len(eig_vals))]
    eig_pairs.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

    matrix_w = eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(y,1)
    for ar in range(1, ndimension):
    matrix_w = np.hstack((matrix_w, eig_pairs[ar][1].reshape(y,1)))

   FinalData = (mean_data.dot(matrix_w))

   return FinalData

xtrain = PCA(train_images,40)
xtest = PCA(test_images, 40)   

r=0
w=0
num = len(xtest)
for i in range(num):
    t = xtest[i]
    j = getNearestSampleIndex(t, xtrain)

    if (np.all(train_labels[j] == test_labels[i])):
        r+=1
    else:
    w+=1

print ("tested ", num, " digits")
print ("correct: ", r, "wrong: ", w, "error rate: ", float(w)*100/(r+w), "%")
print ("got correctly ", float(r)*100/(r+w), "%")
```

Comment: What is the theoretical base of your check (why comparing PCA=linear with KNN=nonlinear)?

Comment: My main goal is to digit recognition, therefore i found this implementation from somewhere else. Original code was using scikit learn pca, so i tried to implement my pca to better understand pca and see if i could succeed. Btw i'm open to any suggesiton to solve this problem by any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

I d'ont know why you are dividing cp.cov() by x-1 and you use np.hstack, here is i think a much simple version of PCA(tested and compared witch scikit) each data is a column vector shape(N,1)

```
def myPCA(data, n_comp=3):
   d= data - data.mean(axis = 1).reshape(data.shape[0], 1)
   c = np.cov(d)
   eigvals, eigvect = np.linalg.eigh(c)
   ind = np.argsort(eigvals)
   ind = ind[::-1]
   eigvals = eigvals[ind]
   eigvect = eigvect[:,ind]
   data_projected = (d.T @ eigvect[:,:n_comp]).T
   return eigvals[:n_comp], eigvect[:,:n_comp], data_projected
```